# $G=GL(2, \mathbb F)$, $X=Mat(2, \mathbb F)$. Describe all orbits and stabilizers of group action $g.x=gxg^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\mathbb F$ is a field.

$G=GL(2, \mathbb F)$ is the group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices.  $X=Mat(2, \mathbb F)$ is the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices. Let $g \in G$, $x \in X$. Group actions is defined $g.x=gxg^{-1}$.

Describe all orbits and stabilizers.

**So far** what I've realized is that the orbits are conjugacy classes, and that every class is the collections of matrices that are similar to each other.

$orb(I)=\{I\}$ and $orb(O_{2 \times 2})=\{O_{2 \times 2}\}$.

Two matrices are similar iff they have the same Jordan form. But how do I describe the Jordan form on an arbitrary field?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want the Frobenius canonical form = rational canonical form.